# java.lang.IllegalStateException: start tag has already been written wso2 as

Tags: java, spring, web-services, wso2

I created a JAX-WS project wso2 developer studio. 
In this project I inherited from interface DocumentRegistryPortType we can find in the lib developed by Rahul(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/rahulsom/ihe-iti/0.7/ihe-iti-0.7.jar)!.
 When I try to access the wsdl in the WSO2 AS shows me the following error.

```
[2014-05-19 01:15:46,943]  INFO {org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean} -  Creating Service {urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007}DocumentRegistry_Service from class ihe.iti.xds_b._2007.DocumentRegistryPortType
[2014-05-19 01:15:51,080]  INFO {org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry} -  Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6bc684d1: defining beans [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,DocumentRegistry]; root of factory hierarchy
[2014-05-19 01:15:51,081] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext} -  StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DocumentRegistry': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: start tag has already been written
```

Any idea what could be this error?

This is my cxf-servlet.xml file. The name of the package is jax and the class is DocumentRegistry. This class implement of DocumetRegistryPortType.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <jaxws:server id="DocumentRegistry" address="/servicio">
        <jaxws:serviceBean>
            <bean  class="jax.DocumentRegistry"/>
        </jaxws:serviceBean>
    </jaxws:server>
</beans>
```

Comment: Seems, it's not related to wso2 application server, you have a syntax error on a spring configuration xml file as error says `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DocumentRegistry': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: start tag has already been written`

Comment: Have a look at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml, and make sure that it does not have any xml syntax errors. This is spring config file which is read by CXF create JAX-WS/RS services.